# $f,g:U^2\to\Bbb R$ smooth. Is $\bar h(x,y)=\int_Uf(x,z)g(z,y)dz$ smooth?

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

> $f,g:U^2\to\Bbb R$ smooth. Is $\bar h(x,y)=\int_Uf(x,z)g(z,y)dz$ smooth?

Under the convention that smooth means element of $C^\infty$, I know that could be rewritten as $\bar h(x,y)=\int_U h_{x,y}(z)dz$, where $h_{x,y}(z)=f(x,z)g(z,y)$ and $h_{x,y}$ is smooth, so the question becomes, is the integral of a smooth function over an integrable region always smooth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, since manifolds are always locally compact. Pick your favourite local coordinates and use Weierstraß' theorem on extremities on compact sets in order to justify the application of differentiation under the integral sign.

EDIT: One may have to decompose the integral into a part that is supported on the respective neighbourhood and another integral, and one will thus need the function $h_{x,y}(z)$ to be in $L^1$.